# Count the number of times the positions of two lists have the same element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If you have two lists,

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 3, 2, 4, 7]
```

how can you count the number of times elements at a certain position coincide? For example 1 and 4 in the above example would have 2 cases of elements coinciding.

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
sum(a_ == b_ for a_, b_ in zip(a, b))
```

Answer (score 3):

`zip` can give you the elements that share a position, and you can use `sum` to count the number of times they match:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 3, 2, 4, 7]

print(sum(x == y for x, y in zip(a, b)))  # 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code and you will get positions which coincide and get sum of them as well.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 3, 2, 4, 7]

print(len([i for i,val in enumerate(zip(a,b)) if val[0]==val[1]]))
```

to get positions you can use

```
print([i for i,val in enumerate(zip(a,b)) if val[0]==val[1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

one more version:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 3, 2, 4, 7]

print(sum(a[i] == b[i] for i in range(len(a))))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
# lists:
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 3, 2, 4, 7]

# initialize variables:
number_of_collisions = 0

# iterate over each element:
for i in range(len(a)):

    if a[i] == b[i]:
        number_of_collisions += 1

print(number_of_collisions)
```